# Read InputStream until 4 specific chars to chars array

Tags: java

How I can read in blocks from `InputStream` to `chars[]` until 4 specific chars?

I'm reading the input byte by byte, but complex condition of an exit from `while` turns out. And reading blocks more efficiently.

```
int p0 = stream.read(),
    p1 = stream.read(),
    p2 = stream.read(),
    p3 = stream.read();
while (!(p0 == a && p1 == b && p2 == c && p3 == d)) {
    result[i] = (char) p0;
    p0 = p1;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = p3;
    p3 = stream.read();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: Will the 4 specific chars always be the last chars of the stream, or might there be further data after these 4 chars?  If there is further data, are you eventually going to read it in the same session?

Comment: @IanMc Further data can be after these four chars.

Comment: After you detect the 4 chars, will you continue to read the stream?  If not, is there a danger to read beyond the 4 chars?  Trying to understand if you can read a large block of data (for efficiency) and then scan the buffer for the 4 chars.

Comment: @IanMc Yes, I can read a large block of data. Read beyond the 4 chars is not dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than reading character by character, create a larger buffer and use a variant of `InputStream#read(buffer[], offset, length)` to fill the buffer.  The following function will efficiently determine the starting location of a 4 character match, or return -1 if none is found.  The `result` then is the sequence of characters (in the buffer) from position 0 to `getIndex(buf)-1`.

```
// Will determine the starting index of the 4 specific characters (or -1)
int getIndex(char buf[]) {

    char c4='z';
    char c3='y';
    char c2='x';
    char c1='w';

    int tail = 3;
    while (tail < buf.length) {
        if (buf[tail] == c4 && buf[tail-1] == c3 && buf[tail-2] == c2 && buf[tail-3] == c1)
            return tail-3;
        tail++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read characters from a stream until the given specific chars :

```
void readWhile(InputStream stream, char[] specificChars) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    char[] buffer = new char[specificChars.length];
    while (reader.read(buffer) != -1) {
        if (Arrays.equals(buffer, specificChars)) {
            // the specific chars were found
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to read actual characters the stream bytes must be decoded using a charset.